# How to create custom maven tasks to execute particular piece of code

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

How to create custom maven tasks to execute particular piece of code.
Eg.: I have src/test/java source folder under which having spec folder. spec package/folder again
have 3 more folders as explained shown in below diagram like: sanity, integration & regression.
[image]

Now my requirement is to deesign custom tasks, which we will be responsible to execute only
specific test cases/classes.

e.g.: Would like to name the task as '`sanity`' so when I execute command like '`mvn sanity`'
it should be able to execute the test cases from sanity package.

Can you please guide how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the maven surefire plugin

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html

with specific `includes`, which can be directory or file patterns. This allows you run only parts of the tests.

Comment: Thanks for update. I am aware with includes tag in surefire plugin, however my requirement is to create new custom tasks rather than including specific files which will run only after mvn test command. I would like to have customs tasks. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "custom task"? You can construct custom command line tasks like "mvn test -Dincludes=..."

Comment: The way we are able to make it in Gradle. E.g. mvn test is default task given by maven. If I wanted to execute test cases from Sanity folder then, is there any way to create a custom task like mvn sanity.....something like that. Thanks!

Comment: You could put the different surefire configurations into profiles, then you could call something like `mvn test -Psanity`, if you call your profile `sanity`.